# What items in Pokémon Go count against item storage limit?

Tags: pokemon-go

What items count against items storage limit and which don’t?

I’ve noticed that not all items in Pokémon Go count against the item storage limit. For example, gifts show as x10 when I have 10 of them, but they do not count towards my max item storage limit. Incubators appear to be excluded from the item count as well - at least to some extent. With so many items now (candies, TMs, evolution items, etc.) I was hoping to know which ones are consuming my item storage.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From a tally of my current items, the following are all counted as 'items' in regards to your item count:

- Potion  (all types)
- Revive  (all types)
- Lucky Egg
- Incense
- TM (all types)
- Rare Candy
- Star Piece
- Pokéballs (all types)
- Lure Module (all types)
- Berries (all types)
- Infinite Incubator
- Purchased Incubators and Super Incubators
- Evolution Items (all types)
- Camera
- Raid Pass (all types)
- Premium Battle Pass
- Mysterious Components and Rocket Radars
- Mystery Box <sup>*</sup>

<sub><sup>*</sup> The Mystery Box does not disappear when used, and is still counted even when not available for use. It is re-loaded when you repeat the procedure connecting to Pokemon Let's Go on a Nintendo Switch.</sub>

Gifts do not count towards the item total. (Neither do gift stickers, but they are not shown in the items list)

Comment: Gifts are also items that don't count towards the item total

Comment: Thanks for the information! It looks like pretty much everything does count towards the total with the exception of gifts (and I’m guessing camera or infinity incubator) after all.

Comment: The camera, infinite incubator, and free raid pass definitely count as items.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler question to answer is "Which items do not count against item storage?"

The simpler answer is gifts and stickers.

Incubators count, but their item count is found in Pokemon storage, in the eggs tab.  You must click on the incubators icon to bring up your incubator inventory.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge today, these don't count: Gift, Stickers, Postcard Book, Daily Adventure Incense, Zygarde Cube, Gimmighoul Coins.